# Pantheon-files asks me for a password to access unprotected SMB shares

Tags: pantheon-files, microsoft-windows, samba, sharing

I used the right-click menu on a Windows 10 computer in order to share a folder on my local network. I set that share to "Everyone" and also disabled password-protected sharing via the Windows Control Panel. But when I'm trying to open it from pantheon-files, this happens:
[image: pantheon-files asking for a password]

I can open the folder using the Windows 10 username and password, but since I'm not the owner of this Windows machine, I would like to know how to setup this share in order to open it without entering a password. Can something be done on the elementary side?